# Constrained matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-rank, linear-matrix-inequality

I have a data matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, with $\mathrm{rank}(X) = n$ and $n \leq m$. I'm trying to understand if I can find some square matrix $C \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ such that

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
& X C = 0,\\
& C^\top \mathbb{1}_m \leq \mathbb{1}_m,\\
& C_i \geq 0,\, i = 1,\ldots,m,
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

where $C_i$ is the $i$-th column of $C$, while $\mathbb{1}_m$ is a column vector of ones of dimension $m$. Obviously, $C = 0$ does the job. Can anyone see some other possibility, or $C = 0$ is the unique solution?

Comment: It is necessary (but I suspect insufficient) that $m \geq n$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann necessary for the uniqueness of $C = 0$? Actually, this is the case, sorry - just edited the question

Comment: Necessary for the existence of a nontrivial solution (a solution besides $C = 0$)

Answer (score 0):

There exist matrices $X$ for which $C = 0$ is the unique solution and others for which it is not.

Note that $C$ satisfies this condition if and only if each column $v$ of $C$ satisfies the conditions
$$
\begin{cases}
Xv = 0,\\
1_m^T v \leq 1,\\
v \geq 0.
\end{cases}
$$
So, it is equivalent to determine the conditions under which the above equation has a solution.

In fact, a non-zero solution to this solution exists if and only if there exists a non-zero first and third conditions, namely
$$
\begin{cases}
Xv = 0,\\
v \geq 0.
\end{cases}
$$
I don't know of any useful alternative formulation for these conditions together with $v \neq 0$.

Comment: I also noticed that any $v \in \mathrm{ker}(X)$. Perhaps another useful information may be that $X$ gathers the vertices of a C-polytope (bounded polyhedral set with nonempty interior containing the origin).